# Есть ли такой плагин для WP или как написать самому?

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

Доброго времени суток, господа! Подскажите, есть ли плагин для WP, который будет создавать вторую страничку в статье, если привышена информация? Хочется, чтобы в статье отображалось 20 картинок, а если их больше - создавать пагинацию(ссылка на вторую страницу и т.д). Писал в файл single.php

```
var a = 0;
$('.entry-content img').each(function(i){
$(this).after($('<span/>', {'class':'img_count'}).text(a = (i+1)));
if (i = 20){$('.count').val;
})
```

Или как-то можно настроить <--nexpage--> ? Подскажите

Answer (score 1):

Вот есть плагин для этого https://wordpress.org/plugins/automatically-paginate-posts/ позволяет автоматически разбивать пост на части.